# Can I use OWIN authentication and SignalR on the same URL path? (e.g. SignalR + Authentication in one call)

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, signalr, owin

SignalR allows me to add credentials directly into its API like this

```
        objConnection.AddClientCertificate = ;
        objConnection.Credentials = ;
```

However, I'm not using certificates, or other Network credentials.  I'm using a custom key pair. I also want to connect to a SignalR Hub and authenticate in one attempt.

Right now my startup looks like this:

```
public static class Startup
{
    public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
         ConfigureSignalR(app);
    }
    public static void ConfigureSignalR(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.Map(("/login"), map =>
            {
                map.Run(async context =>
                    {
                        var token1 = context.Request.Headers["Token"];

                        // if token is valid...

                        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("Custom" );
                        identity.AddClaim("Token", token1);
                        context.Authentication.SignIn(identity);
                    });
            });

        HubConfiguration config = new HubConfiguration();
        config.EnableJSONP = false;
        config.EnableJavaScriptProxies = true;
        config.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        app.MapSignalR(config);
    }
```

I would like to move the above `Context.Authentication.SignIn()` to the method below, however the hub doesn't expose these headers to me.  **CORRECTION** The hub doesn't expose Context.Authentication to me

```
  [HubName("stockTicker")]
  public class StockTickerHub : Hub
  {
    private readonly StockTicker _stockTicker;

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnConnected()
    { 
         // TODO READ HEADERS AND AUTHENTICATE
```

My goal is that that when my C# client logs in (below) ...that I can open the SignalR connection and Authenticate on a single try.

```
 class Program
{
    static HubConnection  objConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:10028/", "DataFrom=0");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        objConnection.Headers.Add("Token", "a TOKEN GOES HERE.. blah");
          IHubProxy proxy = objConnection.CreateHubProxy("stockTicker");
     try
        {
            objConnection.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        proxy.On<Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.StockTicker.Stock>("updateStockPrice", customObject =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(customObject.Symbol + " " + customObject.Price);
        });

        Console.Write("wait");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

If I can't accomplish a one-call SignalR connect and authenticate, how should the C# client "carry over" the authentication into the SignalR call, which I presume will verify the identity using a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably creating a [customized AuthorizeAttribute](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/hub-authorization#custom) that validates that the client has the correct claims to access your Hub. Eg:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
    {
        return IsValid(request.Headers["Token"]);
    }

    private static bool IsValid(string token)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

[HubName("stockTicker")]
[MyAuthorize]
public class StockTickerHub : Hub
{
    // ...
}
```

It is also possible to verify the `ClaimsIdentity`, but this would require extra code on the client-side to retrieve the cookie:

```
// Server

using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

public class AuthorizeClaimsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool UserAuthorized(IPrincipal user)
    {
        var principal = user as ClaimsPrincipal;
        return principal != null && principal.HasClaim("Token", "value");
    }
}

[HubName("stockTicker")]
[AuthorizeClaims]
public class StockTickerHub : Hub
{
    // ...
}

// Client
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", "a TOKEN GOES HERE.. blah");
    await httpClient.GetAsync(url + "/login");
}
objConnection.CookieContainer = handler.CookieContainer;

IHubProxy proxy = objConnection.CreateHubProxy("stockTicker");
await objConnection.Start();
```

Once you create your custom attribute you should attach it to your Hub class.